# Reading a Stored Byte array of binary file as comma separated values in text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

**Problem Statement:**

- I am getting a **text file** where the **byte array** of a binary file is stored in comma-separated values in a single line.
- for Eg: 82,19,176,106,0,0,0,4,247,35,186,20,87,143,18,120,44,76,100
- The string is very long and everything is in a single line , i have no control on this because it depends on binary file size.
- I have to read this byte array and convert it back to the original binary file.

**Implemented Logic:**
using Node.js and FS

```js
var instream = fs.createReadStream('stream1.txt',{ highWaterMark: 1 * 1024  , encoding: 'utf8' });
instream.on("data", function(line) {  
  
  lineCount++;
  var splitArray = line.split(',');  
  var uintArray = new Uint8Array(splitArray); 
  chunks.push(uintArray);
  console.log(lineCount);
});

instream.on("end", function() {  
  var fullUint8Array = concatenate(chunks);
  fs.writeFile("abc.prt", Buffer.from(fullUint8Array), function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Done");
      }
  }); 
});
```

- I am not able to get the original binary file. It is always getting corrupted.
- **If I am reading a file in single chunk and try the above solution it will work. But always this cannot be done because if try to convert a very big string array to uint8Array it gives memory error.**

But when I read the string in chunks and do I am not able to get the binary file.

I am not able to get what I am doing wrong.  Technology to be used Node.JS, javascript.

**Updated The Question with samples**

- This is a sample stream. (stream1.txt)
- This is the original binary file which is needed as output after reading stream1.txt.
- **[Link to the files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AecZ4YMUqyymdanLd5ZcE6zEtlcMJHMh?usp=sharing)**
- Code for concatenate

```js
//For joining uInt8Arrays
function concatenate(arrays) {
  let totalLength = 0;
  for (const arr of arrays) {
    totalLength += arr.length;
  }
  const result = new Uint8Array(totalLength);
  let offset = 0;
  for (const arr of arrays) {
    result.set(arr, offset);
    offset += arr.length;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: How is `concatenate` implemented?

Comment: @JózefPodlecki
The code for the concatenate I will update in original question

Answer (score -1):

> I am not able to get the original binary file. It is always getting
> corrupted.

No, it's not corrupted. The string was splitted by comma, its **unencoded** values were put in `Uint8Array` and later on file is saved with that data.

**This is more or less what's happening**

```js
let line = "82,19,176,106,0,0,0,4,247,35,186,20,87,143,18,120,44,76,100";
let result = line.split(',').map(pr => String.fromCharCode(Number(pr))).join('');
console.log(result);

// Solution 1
let encoded = line.split('').map(npr => npr.charCodeAt(0));
result = encoded.map(pr => String.fromCharCode(pr)).join('');
console.log(result);

// Solution 2
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
encoded = encoder.encode(line);
result = decoder.decode(encoded);
console.log(result);
```

If you apply code above it might look like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
let lineCount = 0;
let chunks = [];

const encoder = new TextEncoder();

function concatenate(chunks) {
  return chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => {
    return new Uint8Array([...acc, ...chunk]);
  }, new Uint8Array([]));
}

var instream = fs.createReadStream('stream1.txt',{ highWaterMark: 1 * 1024  , encoding: 'utf8' });
instream.on("data", function(line) {  
  
  lineCount++;
  var splitArray = line.split(',');
  var uintArray = encoder.encode(line);
  chunks.push(uintArray);
});

instream.on("end", function() {  
  var fullUint8Array = concatenate(chunks);
  fs.writeFile("abc.prt", Buffer.from(fullUint8Array, 'utf-8'), function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Done");
      }
  }); 
});
```

> If I am reading a file in single chunk and try the above solution it
> will work. But always this cannot be done because if try to convert a
> very big string array to uint8Array it gives memory error.

You can reduce memory footprint by creating write stream and putting data immediately there.

**Example**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
let lineCount = 0;
let chunks = [];

const encoder = new TextEncoder();
var outputStream = fs.createWriteStream("abc.prt");
var inputStream = fs.createReadStream('stream1.txt',{ highWaterMark: 1 * 1024  , encoding: 'utf8' });

outputStream.on("open", function() {
  inputStream.on("data", function(line) {  
  
    lineCount++;
    var splitArray = line.split(',');
    var uintArray = encoder.encode(line);
    outputStream.write(uintArray);
  });
  
  inputStream.on("end", function() { 
    outputStream.close();
  })
})
```

Comment: I tried Your solution but still, it did not work. I can share the stream file along with the original binary file. I will attach to the original Question.

Comment: Which part is not working and which solution did you choose?

Comment: What do you mean by "*unencoded values*"? The OP is dealing with raw bytes, there is no encoding. The `split(',')` produces an array of integer strings, which are getting parsed into byte values by the `Uint8Array` constructor. After that, they're just written to the output file.

Comment: **After that, they're just written to the output file.** And after he opens the file with his favourite text viewer and sees gibberish because program decodes those byte values as literal unicode values. Seriously can't you see the difference?

Comment: @JózefPodlecki No. OP said it's a binary file (and uses some `.prt` file extension for the output, apparently some CAD data). Why do you expect them to open it in a text viewer? Also, if the bytes *were* gibberish, to what would you decode them?

Comment: Right, the OP didn't tell us how he opens the file/ checks if file is valid. I thought extension isn't relevant here. My bad. Looks like *Needs details or clarity* flag is needed. Some `autocad` related tag might also help get this question an answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are reading a file in chunks, you need to adjust your splitting logic to cope with that. Your code probably does produce the corrupt results because an input string like `82,19,176,106,0,0` could be read as `82,19,17`+`6,106,0,0` or `82,19`+`,176,106,`+`0,0`.

Instead, you need to make sure that you always read whole byte values. If it is not followed by a comma or the eof, you cannot process it yet. I'd recommend to do this with a [Transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream) (see also [this article](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/practical-examples-of-the-new-node-js-streams-api/) about the technique):

```
import { createReadStream, createWriteStream } from 'fs';
import { pipeline, Transform } from 'stream';

const parseCommaSeparatedBytes = new Transform({
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    const prefix = this.leftover || '';
    const string = prefix + chunk.toString();
    // TODO: validate inputs to be numeric and in the byte range
    const splitArray = string.split(',');
    if (splitArray.length)
      this.leftover = splitArray.pop();
    this.push(new Uint8Array(splitArray));
    callback();
  },
  flush(callback) {
    const last = this.leftover || '';
    if (last.length)
      this.push(new Uint8Array([last]));
    callback();
  },
});

const instream = createReadStream('stream1.txt', {
  highWaterMark: 1024,
  encoding: 'utf8'
});
const outstream = createWriteStream('abc.prt');

pipeline(instream, parseCommaSeparatedBytes, outstream, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Done");
  }
});
```

Comment: I agree with your answer. So my problem still persists. What might be the solution I can implement to handle this?